# Dataloss when saving images binary data 'as file'

Tags: binary, jpeg

I'm kinda a programming noobie but here it goes:

I opened an image file with the program binaryviewer (http://www.proxoft.com/BinaryViewer.aspx) to see its binary code.
Then I used its copy function to first copy the binary data as a .txt file, then as a .jpeg file. The resulting files are quite smaller than the original image file and are completely not readable as images.

Why are the resulting images so much smaller? What kind of data is getting lost in this process and are there ways to prevent that?

Are there specific ways to recreate the image of a file containing only the 0s and 1s of a original image file?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever binary viewer you are using, it just looks at the raw bytes as stored in the file on the disk.

1) When saving 'as text' is itself determines in which format it writes the binary information to a text file. You should look that up in its documentation.

2) It is very unlikely that it has knowledge about the structure of jpg files. So again, when you save to a .jpg file, it itself chooses how to output the bytes, dumps them to a file **named** .jpg, but it does not have the on-disk structure of a .jpg. For any image viewer trying to read the file, it's just garbage.

But as I said in my comments, without knowing what 'binary viewer' you are talking about it's not possible to be more specific.

Comment: then in regards to your answer of point 2) would there be a specific way to get the the structere intact or recreate the structure again? i mean in the end the machine works with zeros and ones too or am i totally wrong there?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why are you even doing this? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Time to edit your question again ;-)

Comment: well i had an idea about lossless compretion of data especially images, music etc on the binary level. but to test my idea i first need a reliable way to get to the binary space and back.

Comment: Using an image as source to test your own compression method won't work because the image data on disk (in the file) is already compressed and contains bookkeeping information. If that's the way you want to go 1) study your compression mechanism on any kind of data 2) find out how to load an image in memory and how to get at the individual color pixels in uncompressed form - which is a whole different issue alltogether. The bottom line is you have to work from the bottom up and don't try "all at once".

Comment: Ha and here i stand thinking i could use a shortcut and have it easy for once XD alright that makes defnitly sense and thanks for pointing me into the right direction, that definitly saved me a lot of time! should i now delete the question or should i just edit it to say its finished?

Comment: Hard to tell. Would it help anyone else? In these cases I tend to leave it open and if other people find it useless they will vote it down; in which case you can still delete - and retrieve the negative downvotes on your reputation ;-)